# How do I look for corrupt files using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, corruption

I'm using an old mac laptop in which Time Machine doesn't work. I have to back things up manually by copying folders and files to my external hard drive. However, when it comes across a corrupt file (mostly the corrupt files are pictures), it stops moving the file. It won't let me move the other files, it just stops moving things. I like using Applescript for stuff like this, as it is like plain English! Here's what I tried:

```
tell application "Finder"
set iphotolibrary to "/Users/sbrenner/Desktop/iPhoto Library 20-26-43"
end tell
tell application "Finder"
search for alias in folder iphotolibrary
end tell
```

It doesn't give me a Syntax error when I compile it, but when I run it, it says:

"Finder got an error: Can’t continue search."

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: The Finder doesn't have a command named "search", you will need to use the term "my" when targeting one your own handlers in an application tell statement. I suspect that you don't have this search handler, so what is "search for alias in folder iphotolibrary" supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. the normal way to handle an exceptional condition in an AppleScript without breaking control flow is to wrap the problematic code section in a `try … on error … end` construct. The [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) has a complete documentation of error handling in [its appendix C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).
2. however, in the case of of your code, the issue is not a corrupt file or other condition, but, as indicated by the error text which corresponds to error code  –1708 (unhandled event), your use of `search`, a term not supported by Finder’s AppleScript dictionary, inside a `tell` block which sets its scope to be Finder’s (as correctly stated by @[Red_Menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866649/red-menace) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470696/how-do-i-look-for-corrupt-files-using-applescript#comment11984524_9470696)). Either you have defined your own `search for` handler, in which case you need to use `my search for`, or you haven’t, in which case your code will not work no matter what.

Comment: You’d have to state what the code is meant to do  for me to answer that – as your question stands, there just is some AppleScript code that cannot do whatever it is meant to … so, to go back one step: what is the script meant to achieve, exactly? `search for alias in` won’t do anything – `search` is not a defined handler and `alias` is a reserved keyword (hence cannot be used for a variable name). Please flesh out your question and I’ll do my best!

Comment: It is meant to find corrupt files.